# mover archivo en php sin reemplazar

Tags: php

estoy tratando de mover un archivo desde php pero sin reemplazar si ya existe.

El caso es que no tengo muy claro como hacerlo si existe mas de uno.

El código que estoy usando es este:

```
        $extension = explode(".", $_GET["foto"]);
        if (file_exists("../../Nuevas/".$Resultados['codigo'].".CR2")) { $nombrenuevo=$Resultados['codigo']."-1.CR2" } else { $nombrenuevo=$Resultados['codigo'].".CR2"; }
        if (rename ("../Fotos/cr2/".$extension[0].".CR2", "../../Nuevas/".$nombrenuevo)) {
        if (!unlink("../Fotos/jpg/".$_GET["foto"])) { $error = "Error Borrando ".$_GET["foto"]; }
        $ok = "el nombre del fichero ha sido cambiado\n";
} else {
        $error = "Se ha producido un error al intentar cambiar el nombre\n";
}
```

Pero en el caso que exista mas de dos archivos con el mismo nombre el segundo se reemplaza. ¿hay alguna forma de que mire si existe mas de uno?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Posible solución que he aplicado.

```
$extension = explode(".", $_GET["foto"]);
        $nombrenuevo=$Resultados['codigo'].".CR2";
        if (file_exists("../../Nuevas/".$nombrenuevo)) {
            for ($i=1; ; $i++){
                if (!file_exists("../../Nuevas/".$Resultados['codigo']."-".$i.".CR2")) { $nombrenuevo=$Resultados['codigo']."-".$i.".CR2"; break; }
            }
        if (rename ("../Fotos/cr2/".$extension[0].".CR2", "../../Nuevas/".$nombrenuevo)) {
        if (!unlink("../Fotos/jpg/".$_GET["foto"])) { $error = "Error Borrando ".$_GET["foto"]; http_response_code(500); }
        $ok = "el nombre del fichero ha sido cambiado\n";
} else {
        $error = "Se ha producido un error al intentar cambiar el nombre\n"; http_response_code(500);
}
```

De momento no puedo probar si funciona ya que tengo un error de sintaxis y estoy buscando el fallo.

Comment: No estoy muy puesto en computacion cuantica pero en la normal no deja tener dos archivos con el mismo nombre a no ser que tengan diferente extension, index.html index.php, puedes explicar el caso un poco mas detalladamente? mientras tanto te pongo un ejemplo de lo que creo que quieres conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo un directorio `files`:

`-->files
 |_archivo1.txt (lo llamaremos original)
 |_carpeta1
   |_archivo1.txt (lo llamaremos copia)`

Y el planteamiento siguiente

`<?php 
/*
  1° obtener lista de archivos del directorio de destino 
  2° comprobar si en esta lista existe un archivo con el mismo que nuestro original
  3° en el caso de que no existe una copia mover el original
*/
?>`

Podriamos tener este tambien:

`<?php 
/*
  1° intentar obtener el archivo en el destino
  2° en el caso de que no exista una copia mover el original
*/
?>`

Yo apuesto por la segunda, ya que es más rápida. Y en parte es la que usas pero estas haciendo un explode para obtener la extension del archivo. Que pasa si el archivo contiene varios puntos ?

`Ej: mi.archivo.txt.doc.txt`

La extension no seria valida y por lo tanto el resto del proceso tampoco.

La mejor opción es tratar el nombre entero. Este es un ejemplo muy básico:

`<?php 
  $destino = 'files/carpeta1/';
  $origen = 'files/archivo1.txt';
  $nombreArchivo = end(explode('/', $origen));
  $pathFinal = $destino . $nombreArchivo;
  if(!file_exists($pathFinal)) {
     try {
      rename($origen , $pathFinal);
      unlink($origen);
     } catch($error) {
       exit($error);
     }
  }
?>`

**Actualización**

El uso de la funcion glob permite consultar todos los archivos que cumplen un patron. Esto nos ayuda a filtrar por nuestro patron hacer un count y poner un numero de archivo copia adecuado.

Aqui la documentacion oficial
http://php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php

Comment: la extension es siempre la misma... se trataría de poner un -1,-2,-3 etc.

Comment: @Killipe, es decir que si tengo a.txt , copie a a-1.txt , y en el caso de que tambien tenga a-1.txt le de a-2.txt y asi continuadamente hasta que no se repita ?

Comment: si. Exactamente eso es :)

Comment: Podrias incluir este detalle en la descripcion? asi te puede ayudar mas personas con sus soluciones :). Por otro lado bastaria con contar el numero de archivos en la carpeta ? eso suponiendo que esta carpeta solo se utilice para este proposito

Comment: Me has dado una idea. Voy a probar con un loop que se pare en cuanto no exista. A ver si lo consigo

Comment: @Killpe no creo que sea la solucion mas optima aunque pueda funcionar, imagina que tienes 100000 archivos xD te revientas tu solo tu server. Los loops no suelen ser muy amigos en estos temas y menos si atacas constantemente y tan rápido al sistema de archivos. Mejor con una mezcla de esto y regular expression no :D?

Comment: nah, son solo Maximo 10 archivos. he puesto esto if (file_exists("../../Nuevas/".$nombrenuevo)) {
   for ($i=1; $i<500; $i++){
    if (!file_exists("../../Nuevas/".$Resultados['codigo']."-".$i.".CR2")) { $nombrenuevo=$Resultados['codigo']."-".$i.".CR2"; break; }
   }

Comment: @Killpe Por favor mueve tu solución debajo de tu pregunta, con un titulo de actualización usando el editor de codigo asi es mas  "readable" para todos, por otro lado no hace falta ? pero usas un loop con 500 vueltas XD

Comment: Puesto... a ver si encuentro el fallo de sintaxis para ver si va